# Is It possible to change line direction d3 GeoJson?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I am using d3 v7 with Vue js and drawing world map. I wanted to connect two points using lat/long but it is taking closest direction. How can I change it as link below? Yellow line is being drown by d3, what i want is white line, Is it possible to change? Thank you so much.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJM1k.png

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56562231/7106086), you need to project the lat/long pairs and then use those coordinates to draw a line as you would between any two SVG coordinates.

Comment: Can you please share a working codepen? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @Shreshth thank you so much your help, I could figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.